# Getting 502 response upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream on elastic beanstalk using Nginx + puma

Tags: server, nginx, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error in log files. it happens when a person reloads page many times. other than that website is working fine. I'm using elastic beanstalk with Nginx + Puma.

`upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.XX.XX.XX, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "example.com"`

Also, I've added these configurations for the Nginx but these configurations didn't fix the problem.

```
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_read_timeout 300;
```

Comment: Puma is terminating the connection request for some reason - usually this happens when Puma is down or misconfigured in some way and not passing data back and forth properly.  Have you verified that Puma itself is actually functioning and not out of memory or resources?  (Might be in puma logs not nginx logs)

Comment: puma is working,  also when  I reload after getting 502 errors. it works perfectly.  It happens when a person reloads a page for more than 5 times.

Comment: Yes, verified the puma logs to.

Comment: according to the doc `proxy_connect_timeout ~Defines a timeout for establishing a connection with a proxied server. It should be noted that this timeout cannot usually exceed 75 seconds.`